# How to include seconds in the jquery datetimepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, datetimepicker

I am planning to use [this](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)'s datetimepicker plugin. But in documentation also couldn't find about seconds part. Can you guys help me how to provide seconds in this plugin. Seconds is the mandatory thing for the requirement or suggest any good MIT open license plugin which has seconds also for date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="calendar">

$('#calendar').datetimepicker({
        format:'d/m/Y H:i:s'
});
```

By adding format as an option in datetimepicker as above it is taking the seconds. Seconds are not showing in datetimepicker ui but taking current seconds and displaying in the input box then we can edit as per our requirement. If any one find a way to show seconds in the ui also that could be appreciable.

This is my first answer please let me correct if I committed any mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

add following JQuery code...

```
$('#yourexample').datetimepicker({
   showSecond: true,
   showMillisec: true,
   timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss:l'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I tried but not working.
<input id="calendar">
 <script>
$(function(){
 $('#calendar').datetimepicker({
   showSecond: true,
      showMillisec: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss:l'
  });
});

Can you see any wrong i had done in above code
.

Comment: I tried like this worked fine 
$('#calendar').datetimepicker({
        format:'d/m/Y H:i:s'
});

But not showing seconds option in datetimepicker ui even taking current seconds and showing in the above format in input box and then we can able to edit it as per our requirement.

Any way you find to show seconds in ui more helpful to me.

Thank you. @Ani

Answer (score 1):

By adding

```js
$('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true,
      timePickerSeconds: true,
      timePickerIncrement: 30,
      locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss'
      }
    })
```

It worked for displaying seconds in datetimePicker UI.